# Progress Bar does not go after completion

Tags: android, progress-bar, visibility

I am using a horizontal Progress Bar. It works fine but does not disappear after completion of time.

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
progressBar.setRotation(180);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 21) {
            progressStatus += 1;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(110);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}).start();
```

}

The setVisibility() function at the end of while statement crashes my app.

Logcat:

```
12-24 09:55:54.502    7160-7245/com.food.foodjugaad E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-25568
Process: com.food.foodjugaad, PID: 7160
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6462)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:897)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17494)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9726)
        at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6698)
        at android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.java:1546)
        at com.food.foodjugaad.Swipe$2.run(Swipe.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android only had 1 thread to update UI, It is UI Thread, any others thread couldn't update UI , If your do it will throw exceptions. I edited your code. Could you try it.

```
 progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
progressBar.setRotation(180);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < 21) {
            progressStatus += 1;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(110);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){                     
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I have posted the LogCat.

Comment: The android only had 1 thread to update UI. But you call update in another thread so it throw that error. You need to call setVisible in UI Thread. I edited my post with your code. Could you try it.

Comment: Worked. Thankyou so much!!

Comment: don't know why this answer was downvoted.but its a right one

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify widgets from the main thread. Do another runnable to change the visibility.

Comment: Okay I am giving it a try.